# Easeljs - creating a neon drawing application - with undo, delete, brush size, colour options

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I've developing a drawing application, which would allow the user to draw a neon like doodle. Most of the functionality works - but I am having issues with the "undo" function. I try and remove the last child from the drawingcanvas - but it doesn't make any difference

//
Canvas code 
//

```
var app ={
        stage:null,
        stagetools:null,
        erase:0,
        container:null,
        loader:null, 
        stageArea:null,
        backgroundContainer:null,
        backgroundBounds:null,
        oldPt:0,
        oldMidPt:0,
        midPt:0, 
        NUM_LINES: -1,
        manifest:[],
        toolsAssets:[],
        lineArray:[],
        lineArray2:[],
        lineArray3:[],
        filters2:[],
        filters:[],
        mouseDOWN:false,
        bgscale:true,
        maskFilter:null,
        init: function(chosenNum){
            //setup
            this.stagetools = new createjs.Stage('canvasTools');
            this.stagetools.enableDOMEvents(true);
            this.stagetools.enableMouseOver(10);
            createjs.Touch.enable(this.stagetools);

            this.stage = new createjs.Stage('canvas'); 
            this.stage.autoClear = true;
            this.stage.enableDOMEvents(true);
            this.stage.snapToPixelEnabled = true;
            this.stage.enableMouseOver(10);
            createjs.Touch.enable(this.stage);
            createjs.Ticker.setFPS(5000); 
            createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', this.tick); 

            //loader
            this.manifest = [
                {src:'images/brush.png',    id:'brush',    link: 'tool'},   
                {src:'images/undo.png',     id:'undo',     link: 'tool'},
                {src:'images/eraser.png',   id:'eraser',   link: 'tool'},
                {src:'images/clear.png',    id:'clear',    link: 'tool'}
            ];

            switch(chosenNum)
            {
                case 0: this.manifest.push({src:'images/NeonCanvases-image1.jpg',id:'fc0', link:'car'}); break;  
                case 1: this.manifest.push({src:'images/NeonCanvases-image2.jpg',id:'fc1', link:'car'}); break;    
                case 2: this.manifest.push({src:'images/NeonCanvases-image3.jpg',id:'fc2', link:'car'}); break;       
                case 3: this.manifest.push({src:'images/NeonCanvases-image4.jpg',id:'fc3', link:'car'}); break;   
                case 4: this.manifest.push({src:'images/NeonCanvases-image5.jpg',id:'fc4', link:'car'}); break;
                case 5: this.manifest.push({src:'images/NeonCanvases-image6.jpg',id:'fc5', link:'car'}); break;
                default: this.manifest.push({src:'images/NeonCanvases-image1.jpg',id:'fc0', link:'car'}); break;  
            }
            console.log("v3");
            this.loader = new createjs.LoadQueue();
            this.loader.on('complete', this.handleComplete);
            this.loader.on("fileload", this.handleFileLoad);
            this.loader.loadManifest(this.manifest);                

            var drawingsArray = [];

            this.stage = new createjs.Stage('canvas'); 

            //__add car background
            this.backgroundContainer = new createjs.Container();
            this.stage.addChild(this.backgroundContainer);

            //stage.enableDOMEvents(true);
            createjs.Touch.enable(this.stage);
            createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60); 
            createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', this.stage); 

            //__the drawing space
            this.stageArea  = new createjs.Container();
            this.stageArea.snapToPixelEnabled = true;
            this.stageArea.hitArea = new createjs.Shape(new createjs.Graphics().f("#000").dr(0,0,960,window.innerHeight));
            this.stageArea.cache(0,0,960,window.innerHeight); // Cache it.
            this.stage.addChild(this.stageArea);

            //__resolve container with tool kit.
            this.container = new createjs.Container();      
            this.stage.addChild(this.container);    

            /*
            // Create the shape to draw into
            this.drawing = new createjs.Shape();
            this.drawing.shadow = new createjs.Shadow('#0066cc',1, 1, 30);
            this.stageArea.addChild(this.drawing);
            */
            this.erase = 0;//initially its a fill pen
            this.lastPoint = new createjs.Point();

            var that = this;
            this.stageArea.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
                // Store the position. We have to do this because we clear the graphics later.
                that.lastPoint.x = event.stageX;
                that.lastPoint.y = event.stageY;
            });

            // Listen for mousemove
            this.stageArea.addEventListener("pressmove", function(event){
                console.log("pressmove");

                var drawingCanvas = new createjs.Shape();
                drawingCanvas.shadow = new createjs.Shadow('#0066cc',1, 1, 30);
                app.stageArea.addChild(drawingCanvas);              

                // Draw a round line from the last position to the current one.
                drawingCanvas.graphics.setStrokeStyle(tools.size, "round", "round");
                drawingCanvas.graphics.beginStroke(tools.COLOUR);
                drawingCanvas.graphics.moveTo(that.lastPoint.x, that.lastPoint.y);
                drawingCanvas.graphics.lineTo(event.stageX, event.stageY);

                // Draw a round line from the last position to the current one.

                drawingCanvas.graphics.clear();
                //__white line
                drawingCanvas.graphics.setStrokeStyle(tools.size, "round", "round", 1, true);
                drawingCanvas.graphics.beginStroke('#fff');
                drawingCanvas.graphics.moveTo(that.lastPoint.x, that.lastPoint.y);
                drawingCanvas.graphics.lineTo(event.stageX, event.stageY);  
                //__white line              

                //set shadows
                drawingCanvas.shadow = new createjs.Shadow(tools.COLOUR,1, 1, 30);

                // Update the last position for next move.
                that.lastPoint.x = event.stageX;
                that.lastPoint.y = event.stageY;

                // Draw onto the canvas, and then update the container cache.
                app.stageArea.updateCache(app.erase?"destination-out":"source-over");

                drawingCanvas.graphics.clear();
            });             
        },

        handleFileLoad:function(e){
            app.toolsAssets.push(e);    
        },

        handleComplete:function(){      
            tools.init();
            //background
            for(var i = 0; i < app.toolsAssets.length; i++){
                if(app.toolsAssets[i].item.link == "car"){
                    var imgLoader = app.loader.getResult(app.toolsAssets[i].item.id);
                    var img = new createjs.Bitmap(imgLoader);

                    app.backgroundBounds = img.getBounds();
                    app.backgroundContainer.addChild(img);
                    img.cache(0,0, img.getBounds().width, img.getBounds().height);
                }
            }
            resize();
        },

        tick:function(){
            //console.log("ticks");

        }
    }

    var tools = {

        selectedArray:[],
        undoArray:[],
        undoArray2:[],
        undoArray3:[],
        palettes: ['#0066cc', '#0ceaed', '#00ff2a', '#de00ff', '#f40045', '#d8ff00','#ff8400','#7d36ff'],
        sizes:[6, 10, 15],
        colourPallette:null,
        paletteColours: null,
        brushSizes:null,
        toolsContainer:null,
        size: 8,
        toolsScale:1,
        COLOUR: '#0066cc',
        SELECTED:0,
        eraser: false,
        init:function(){
            //colour pallette
            this.toolsContainer = new createjs.Container();
            this.toolsContainer.x = app.stagetools.canvas.width/2 - 150;
            this.toolsContainer.y = app.stagetools.canvas.height/2 + 10;
            app.stagetools.addChild(this.toolsContainer);

            this.colourPallette = new createjs.Shape();
            this.colourPallette.name = 'colourPallette';
            this.colourPallette.graphics.beginFill(tools.COLOUR);
            this.colourPallette.graphics.setStrokeStyle(4, 'round').beginStroke("#FFFFFF");
            this.colourPallette.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,22);
            this.colourPallette.addEventListener('click', this.palletteHandler);
            this.toolsContainer.addChild(this.colourPallette);

            this.paletteColours = new createjs.Container();
            this.paletteColours.visible = false;
            this.toolsContainer.addChild(this.paletteColours);

            for(var i = 0; i < this.palettes.length; i++){
                var palette = new createjs.Shape();
                palette.name = 'palette' + i;
                palette.graphics.beginFill(this.palettes[i]);
                palette.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,15);
                palette.addEventListener('click', this.palletteHandler);
                palette.x = (i * 50);
                palette.y = -50;
                this.paletteColours.addChild(palette);
            }

            //brush tool
            var brush = new createjs.Bitmap(app.loader.getResult('brush'));
            brush.name = 'brush';
            brush.x = 50;
            brush.y = -34;
            brush.addEventListener('click', this.brushHandler);
            this.toolsContainer.addChild(brush);    

            this.brushSizes = new createjs.Container();
            this.brushSizes.x = brush.x + 40;
            this.brushSizes.y = brush.y - 20;
            this.brushSizes.visible = false;
            this.toolsContainer.addChild(this.brushSizes);

            for(var p = 0; p < this.sizes.length; p++){
                var size = new createjs.Shape();
                size.name = 'size'+p;
                size.graphics.beginFill('#FFFFFF');
                size.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,this.sizes[p]);
                size.addEventListener('click', this.brushHandler);     
                size.x = (p==1) ? p * 40 : p * 45; 
                this.brushSizes.addChild(size);
            }

            //undo tool
            var undo = new createjs.Bitmap(app.loader.getResult('undo'));
            undo.name = 'undo';
            undo.x = brush.x + 90;
            undo.y = brush.y;
            undo.addEventListener('click', this.undoHandler); 
            this.toolsContainer.addChild(undo); 

            //eraser tool
            var eraser = new createjs.Bitmap(app.loader.getResult('eraser'));
            eraser.name = 'eraser';
            eraser.x = undo.x + 90;
            eraser.y = undo.y;
            eraser.addEventListener('click', this.eraserHandler); 
            this.toolsContainer.addChild(eraser);

            //trash tool
            var clear = new createjs.Bitmap(app.loader.getResult('clear'));
            clear.name = 'clear';
            clear.x = eraser.x + 90;
            clear.y = eraser.y;
            clear.addEventListener('click', this.clearHandler); 
            this.toolsContainer.addChild(clear);    
        },

        brushHandler:function(e){

            tools.paletteColours.visible = false;
            tools.brushSizes.visible = false;

            switch(e.target.name)
            {
                 case 'size0': tools.size = 6; break;
                 case 'size1': tools.size = 10; break;
                 case 'size2': tools.size = 15; break;
                 case 'brush': tools.brushSizes.visible = true; break;
            }

            app.stagetools.update();
        },

        palletteHandler:function(e){

            tools.paletteColours.visible = false;
            tools.brushSizes.visible = false;

            switch(e.target.name)
            {

             case 'colourPallette': tools.paletteColours.visible = true; break;

             case 'palette0':
                    tools.SELECTED = 0;
                    tools.COLOUR = '#0066cc';
                    break;

             case 'palette1':
                    tools.SELECTED = 1;
                    tools.COLOUR = '#0ceaed';
                    break;  

             case 'palette2':
                    tools.SELECTED = 2;
                    tools.COLOUR = '#00ff2a';
                    break;      

             case 'palette3':
                    tools.SELECTED = 3;
                    tools.COLOUR = '#de00ff';
                    break;

             case 'palette4':
                    tools.SELECTED = 4;
                    tools.COLOUR = '#f40045';
                    break;  

             case 'palette5':
                    tools.SELECTED = 5;
                    tools.COLOUR = '#d8ff00';
                    break;      

             case 'palette6':
                    tools.SELECTED = 6;
                    tools.COLOUR = '#ff8400';
                    break;  

             case 'palette7':
                    tools.SELECTED = 7;
                    tools.COLOUR = '#7d36ff';
                    break;                          
            }

            tools.colourPallette.graphics.beginFill(tools.COLOUR);
            tools.colourPallette.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,22);

            app.stagetools.update();
        },

        eraserHandler: function(){
            console.log("erase");
            app.erase = 1 - app.erase;
        },

        undoHandler:function(){
            console.log("undo bit");

            if(app.stageArea.children.length > 1){
                var lastChild = app.stageArea.children.pop(1);
                app.stageArea.removeChild(lastChild);
                app.stage.update();
            }

        },

        clearHandler:function(e){
            console.log("clear");
            app.stageArea.removeAllChildren();
            app.stageArea.updateCache();
            app.stage.update();
        },
    }

    function resize(){
        app.stage.canvas.width = $('#canvas').parent().width();
        //app.stage.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        app.stagetools.canvas.width = $('#canvas').parent().width();


        //tools container
        if(app.stage.canvas.width < 960){
            app.stage.canvas.height = '960';
        }

        if(app.stage.canvas.width < 860){
            app.stage.canvas.height = '860';
        }

        if(app.stage.canvas.width < 760){
            app.stage.canvas.height = '760';
        }

        if(app.stage.canvas.width < 660){
            app.stage.canvas.height = '660';
        }

        if(app.stage.canvas.width < 560){
            app.stage.canvas.height = '560';
        }

        if(app.stage.canvas.width < 460){
            app.stage.canvas.height = '460';
        }

        if(app.stage.canvas.width < 300){
            app.stage.canvas.height = '300';
            tools.toolsScale = 0.7;
        }


        tools.toolsContainer.scaleX = tools.toolsScale;
        tools.toolsContainer.scaleY = tools.toolsScale;
        tools.toolsContainer.x = app.stagetools.canvas.width/2 - 150 * tools.toolsScale;


        //content scale
        app.container.scaleX = app.bgscale;
        app.container.scaleY = app.bgscale;
        app.container.x = app.stage.canvas.width/2;
        app.container.y = app.stage.canvas.height/2;

        //background image      
        app.bgscale = app.stage.canvas.width /  app.backgroundBounds.width;

        if(app.backgroundBounds.height * app.bgscale > app.stage.canvas.height){
           app.bgscale = app.stage.canvas.height /  app.backgroundBounds.height;
        }

        app.backgroundContainer.scaleX = app.bgscale;
        app.backgroundContainer.scaleY = app.bgscale;

        app.backgroundContainer.x = Math.floor(app.stage.canvas.width/2 - app.backgroundBounds.width/2 * app.bgscale);
        app.backgroundContainer.y = Math.floor(app.stage.canvas.height/2 - app.backgroundBounds.height/2 * app.bgscale);

        app.stage.update();
        app.stagetools.update();
}
```

Comment: Do you have a working fiddle that we can experiment with and see what actually IS happening?

Comment: I could try and create one - this is really part of a bigger angular app

Comment: I've made a fiddle - but I can't get it working. http://jsfiddle.net/udp2czqv/2/

Comment: ok got the fiddle going - but the image hot links are not working? http://jsfiddle.net/udp2czqv/4/

Comment: I can't seem to get the images to load - http://jsfiddle.net/udp2czqv/8/

Comment: _ can someone help me with this - any comments/opinions - getting it to work locally?